# Finding Browser Type in CODED UI?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

How can i get the browser type in CODED_UI. I am new to coded ui automation. can you please help me out. Using BrowserWindow can we get the browser type.

Answer (score 0):

By default your Browser type on Coded UI will be Internet explorer. Coded UI Uses Selenium to test Non-IE browsers and **you have to set the browser type you want before you launch the browser.**

So the question of getting your current browser type will be irrelevant, since you are the one setting it. It will be something like this,

```
 BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "Chrome";
 Chrome = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("http://yourwebsite.com"));
```

but, for some reason you do not know what your current browser is you can give a shot at,

```
browser.ClassName;
```

Note: It does not tell u explicitly, you have to extract it.